# librealsense not building

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 $ cmake .. -DBUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=true
-- Building in a ROS environment
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/jackson/github/librealsense/build/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/jackson/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/jackson/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/jackson/github/librealsense/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.18
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
GLFW_LIBRARIES
    linked by target "c-tutorial-1-depth" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "c-tutorial-2-streams" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "c-tutorial-3-pointcloud" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "cpp-alignimages" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "cpp-callback" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "cpp-callback-2" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "cpp-capture" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "cpp-config-ui" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "cpp-enumerate-devices" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "cpp-headless" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "cpp-motion-module" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "cpp-multicam" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "cpp-pointcloud" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "cpp-restart" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "cpp-stride" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "cpp-tutorial-1-depth" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "cpp-tutorial-2-streams" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples
    linked by target "cpp-tutorial-3-pointcloud" in directory /home/jackson/github/librealsense/examples

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/jackson/github/librealsense/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/jackson/github/librealsense/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246444/librealsense-not-building/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-10-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This happens when you don't have the `glfw_libraries` installed. Follow the [librealsense installation](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/installation.md)

```
scripts/install_glfw3.sh
```

---

Originally posted by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) with karma: 396 on 2016-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1